# How do you create a list of users onto an Embed with reactions? [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a queue that lists out a maximum of 10 people on an embed outputted by a command. Basically, users will react to the embed and have their names listed in queue for a game. I'm struggling to understand the proper use of collections and how it can collect user data, then update an existing embed with the collected names. The following is the code that I have worked so far:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'auqueue',
    description: "Among Us Queue for 10-man lobby max",
    async execute(message, args, Discord){
        const playerlist = []
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff1717')
        .setTitle('Among Us Queue')
        .addFields(
            {name: '1', value: [0]},
            {name: '2', value: [0]},
            {name: '3', value: [0]},
            {name: '4', value: [0]},
            {name: '5', value: [0]},
            {name: '6', value: [0]},
            {name: '7', value: [0]},
            {name: '8', value: [0]},
            {name: '9', value: [0]},
            {name: '10', value: [0]})
        .setThumbnail('https://preview.redd.it/an871k4o1sn51.png?width=440&format=png&auto=webp&s=85dcd6cb73b8760802e254ee14dfa3c7ab444591');

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['<:AmongUs:758229906965921802>'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        const messageToReact = await message.channel.send(newEmbed)
        await messageToReact.react("<:AmongUs:758229906965921802>");
        messageToReact.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] });
    }
}
```

PS: I'm quite noob-ish in all this Discord.js coding and haven't gotten much experience in coding in general. Trying to do get into this as a hobby as COVID be keeping me indoors. I will take everyone's input!

Comment: One thing I'll note for you: if you want your queue embed to be edited whenever someone reacts to the message (live representation of who's in the queue), and not edit it once only after 60 seconds have passed (delayed representation of who's in the queue), you'll want to use `messageToReact.createReactionCollector()` instead of `awaitReactions()`. They work similarly, but `awaitReactions` will only execute code after the time is up, while `ReactionCollector` will allow you to execute code each time a reaction is added to the message.

Comment: I advise you to look at the docs for an example on how reaction collectors work [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector)

Comment: You don't do anything with the promise that is returned by messageToReact.AwaitReactions().